# How to find DEM data with attribute table for Brighton UK

Tags: data-request, uk

Where can I find accurate DEM data of Brighton UK (with an attribute table) to be used in ARC GIS, being used for a university GIS project and have struggled to find this data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at OS Terrain 50 https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html